# QMenu Right Align Text

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qmenu

I need the text in my `QMenu` to be right aligned instead of left aligned.

```
QMenu menu;
menu.setStyleSheet("QMenu{background: #2e353d; color: #bfbfbf; margin: 0px;}"
"QMenu::item{font-size: 10pt; padding: " + QString::number(6*globalDPI) + "px " + QString::number(30*globalDPI) + "px " + QString::number(6*globalDPI) + "px " + QString::number(20*globalDPI) + "px; border: 0px solid transparent; margin: 0px;}"
"QMenu::item:selected{background: #373f49; color: #fff;}");

menu.addAction("Debug Log");
menu.addAction("Website");
menu.addAction("Changelog");
menu.addAction("About");

menu.exec(myButton->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,32*globalDPI)));
```

I've tried adding `text-align: right` to both the `QMenu` and `QMenu::item` in the stylesheet. I've tried setting the layout direction to right to left with `setLayoutDirection`. I've tried adding `subcontrol-position: right;` to the stylesheet. Nothing works, the text in the menu remains left aligned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to change the alignment of the QMenu text as it is codified when drawing the QMenu using the QStyle. A workaround is to use a QProxyStyle by doing the painting by passing an empty text in the QStyleOptionMenuItem and then painting the text (the text painting I show is limited since I am not taking all cases such as a QMenu with multiple lines and other options sophisticated).

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>
class MenuProxyStyle: public QProxyStyle{
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *opt, QPainter *p, const QWidget *w) const override
    {
        if(element == QStyle::CE_MenuItem){
            if(const QStyleOptionMenuItem *o = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionMenuItem *>(opt)){
                QStyleOptionMenuItem menuitem = *o;
                QString text = o->text;
                menuitem.text = "";
                QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, &menuitem, p, w);
                if(o->text.isEmpty())
                    return;
                int margin = 4;
                int text_flags = Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignRight | Qt::TextDontClip | Qt::TextSingleLine;
                p->drawText(menuitem.rect.adjusted(margin, margin, -margin, -margin),  text_flags, text);
                return;
            }
        }
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, opt, p, w);
    }
};
class Widget: public QWidget{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr): QWidget(parent){
        setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
        connect(this, &QWidget::customContextMenuRequested, this, &Widget::on_customContextMenuRequested);
    }
private:
    void on_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos){
        QMenu menu;
        menu.setStyle(new MenuProxyStyle(menu.style()));
        menu.addAction("Debug Log");
        menu.addAction("Website");
        menu.addAction("Changelog");
        menu.addAction("About");
        menu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was worried I might have to do something like that... I appreciate the detailed answer, should make my life easier :)